# PHP/HTML - crazy error

Tags: php, html

I've a problem with this code:
 `<meta property="og:url" content="<?= echo 'http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" />`

> ERROR: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)`

please help

Comment: `<?= echo` what's that do?

Comment: crazy(wrong) code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the equal sign (=) after the PHP opening tags `<?=` should be `<?`

Comment: or maybe the alternative .. remove the echo

Answer (score 0):

With `<?=` this `=` means its already going to `echo` anything inside of the tags.

You can either remove the `=` or remove the `echo`

So it should either look like this:

`<meta property="og:url" content="<?= 'http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" />`

or like this:

`<meta property="og:url" content="<? echo 'http://' .$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']. '/' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`